# What causes this difference of syntax?

Tags: php

Look at the code below

```
<?php
echo "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] <br />";
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "\n\n";
?>
```

both of the echo statements return the value of HTTP_HOST index from the superglobal array $_SERVER using the same technique? My question is what caused the difference of the syntax? I noticed the following differences:

1. HTTP_HOST in the first echo statement is not encased in single quotes, it is contrary to the syntax I used in the second echo statement. I get the following error if I encase HTTP_HOST in single quotes for the first echo statement

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-blog\simple-blog\server.php on line 2

1. Why a comma is needed after ['HTTP_HOST'] in the second echo statement while it is not needed in the first echo statement? I get the following error if I discard this comma.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"\n\n"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-blog\simple-blog\server.php on line 3

I am new to programming, need guidance, help please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first statement calls echo with only one argument.
The argument is a string which includes a variable.
When doing this you should use brackets to make sure php understands were your variable starts:

```
 echo "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']} <br>";
```

You could also concatenate strings with a dot:

```
 echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "<br>";
```

The comma is just another way to write several echos at once:

```
echo 1, 2;
```

is the same as

```
echo 1;
echo 2;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 0):

php syntax allows referring to variables inside double-quotes.
for example:

```
$x = "hello";
echo "$x world";
```

is similar to:

```
echo $x . " world";
```

or

```
echo $x , " world";
```

and all will output `hello world`.

notice that referring to variables inside single-quotes is not allowed, and for this reason
`echo '$x world';`
is invalid.